# Error In installimg mideapipe in python 3.11

Tags: pip, python-3.11

I use the latest pythhon ie. 3.11
when run the command in command promt(windows 10)
I got an error of -
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe

please help me
and please release mideapipe for python3.11

Please release it for python 3.11
or help me

don't tell me to downground python

Answer (score 1):

`mediapipe` is not yet released for windows and python 3.11. It is [an open feature request](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/4292) tp release for windows.

> Please release it for python 3.11

I am sorry, but the SO community is not the one maintaining this project, reply to the feature request linked above.

> don't tell me to downground python

This would be the easiest solution though

Alternatively, you could try to start with the [guide on how to compile it on windows](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install#installing_on_windows) and figure out the caveats on the way. But I would assume that it will not work easily.